# Should I return struct by value or by pointer?

Tags: c

I have a function in **C** as follows:

```
GamePiece* init_game_piece(PieceType pieceType, bool isWhite,int column, int row);
```

It allocates memory and I free the object afterwards(I just initiate it and copy it into a list I create )as showed below:

```
List* list = board->gamePieces[PIECES_INDEX(isWhite)][piecesArray[i]];
GamePiece* gamePiece = init_game_piece(piecesArray[i], isWhite,i,NON_PAWN_ROW_INDEX(isWhite));
insert_item(list, gamePiece);
board->boardData[gamePiece->gamePieceCell.row][gamePiece->gamePieceCell.column] = get_last_element(list);
free(gamePiece);
```

Would it be better for me to make the function inline and return it by value?
Like this:

```
GamePiece init_game_piece(PieceType pieceType, bool isWhite,int column, int row);
```

```
List* list = board->gamePieces[PIECES_INDEX(isWhite)][piecesArray[i]];
GamePiece gamePiece = init_game_piece(piecesArray[i], isWhite,i,NON_PAWN_ROW_INDEX(isWhite));
insert_item(list, &gamePiece);
board->boardData[gamePiece->gamePieceCell.row][gamePiece->gamePieceCell.column] = get_last_element(list);
```

Will the inlining just pass it and not copy it?

Comment: It really depends. In this *specific* case it might be a bad idea, since you seem to store a pointer to a local variable (that will go out of scope and cease to exist sooner or later) which is always a bad idea.

Comment: What is `GamePiece`?

Comment: Depends on how you use the function.   If, as you describe, all you're doing is copying the structure to another, and releasing, it would be better to return by value and let the compiler optimise.   In general, however, you would need to test to be sure.

Comment: If `init_game_piece()` allocates memory, that question is irrelevant: Allocation takes much longer than copying a short struct, or any function call overhead.

Comment: I'd say neither. Pass a pointer into `init_game_piece` to initialize. Let the caller decide how they wish to allocate it.

Comment: IMO returning by value is much simpler. If the only use case for the function is to store the returned pointer in a linked list then you may as well have the function allocate tho.

Comment: To expand on @Someprogrammerdude's warning that you're storing the address of a local variable that will _at some time_ go out of scope... if the snippet of code is called more than once (I strongly suspect there's a `for( i=0; ... ; ... )` around it) then you will be using the **same** structure each time and overwriting it. Also, your 2nd snippet would want `gamePiece.` not `gamePiece->`.

Comment: "Would it be better for me to make the function inline and return it by value?" --> What result do you want if allocation failed?  What if a parameter was invalid like `column < 0`?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the code "module" (object, ADT, translation unit, rose by any other name) that does the allocation, is also responsible for deallocation. Everything else is bad design and leads to memory leaks.

Comment: The fact that you allocate something just to free it again almost immediately afterwards should be an indication that there is something not right with this code.

Comment: @SeanBurton I am using this because i am copying items to list using their pointers, my second option would be passing value, but it will result in one more copy than I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Inlining will most probably work the way you suspect; the allocation of the structure will be eliminated, and if you build with optimizations enabled then the structure will in all likelihood simply be declared locally, so you will not even suffer the copying penalty that would be incurred if the function was not inlined.

However, if you use this function in many places, and if the function is lengthy, then the disadvantage will be a larger amount of code, which is a bit worse than you might think, because more code means worse caching behavior, and the performance of modern CPUs is largely dependent on caching.

However, all that is speculative.  You really will not know for sure unless you try, and you should not really try unless you have a very good reason to believe that this part of your program does in fact suffer performance-wise and is in fact in need of optimization.

But if you want to give it a try, the chances are very much in favor of trying, you will most likely get much better performance this way.